# how do you convert json output to a data frame in python

Tags: python, json

I need to convert this json file to a data frame in python:

```
print(resp2)

    {
  "totalCount": 1,
  "nextPageKey": null,
  "result": [
    {
      "metricId": "builtin:tech.generic.cpu.usage",
      "data": [
        {
          "dimensions": [
            "process_345678"
          ],
          "dimensionMap": {
            "dt.entity.process_group_instance": "process_345678"
          },
          "timestamps": [
            1642021200000,
            1642024800000,
            1642028400000
          ],
          "values": [
            10,
            15,
            12
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Output needs to be like this:

```
metricId    dimensions  timestamps  values
builtin:tech.generic.cpu.usage  process_345678  1642021200000   10
builtin:tech.generic.cpu.usage  process_345678  1642024800000   15
builtin:tech.generic.cpu.usage  process_345678  1642028400000   12
```

I have tried this:

```
print(pd.json_normalize(resp2, "data"))
```

I get invalid syntax, any ideas?

Comment: `create DataFrame from data_list` is not valid syntax... Is that part of the code?

Comment: Beyond that, checkout some examples here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I have tried pandas normalize functions, not working

Comment: You didn't answer my first question, and, well, `resp2` includes `totalCount` and `dimensionMap`, which are not in your expected output, so obviously that was wrong... You've asked about 3 similar questions over the last 6 months on how to parse JSON, so what have you learned in order to just get the result list within the data, then remove `dimensionMap`? In other words, you're going to need to _parse_ the data _into a new list_ before you can create the dataframe you want

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I am not familiar with this stuff. And all the examples are not similar to this json file.

Comment: Lesson from JSON parsing - you'll never find specific examples. `{` is the start of an object, and `[` is the start of an array... You always need to start at the top of an object... This applies to all JSON parsing. However, you don't have JSON here, you have a Python dictionary. If the examples don't align perfectly with what you have, the change your data to match it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the examples of [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), and you'll see a list of dictionaries that have the key names of the columns you want, unique to each row. When you have nested lists/objects, then the columns will be flatten to have dot-notation, but nested arrays will not end up duplicated across rows.

Therefore, parse the data into a flat list, then you can use [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html).

```
data = []
for r in resp2['result']:
    metricId = r['metricId']
    for d in r['data']:
        dimension = d['dimensions'][0]  # unclear why this is an array 
        timestamps = d['timestamps']
        values = d['values']
        for t, v in zip(timestamps, values):
            data.append({'metricId': metricId, 'dimensions': dimension,  'timestamps': t, 'values': v})

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```